# Modify variables with a static method

Tags: python, static-methods

I know static methods should be kept to a minimum and the whole idea of static methods is that they don't interact with the class but is there a way to do it?

Requirements:

class System with 2 attributes - divisible and obvisible, which are empty lists

static method register_divisible(name) takes parameter name and appends it to divisible

Example:

```
class System:
    def __init__(self):
        self.divisible = []
        self.obvisible = []

    @staticmethod
    def register_divisible(name):
        self._divisible.append(name)
```

Comment: Hm... You mean is there a way to modify class members with a static method? The whole point of static methods is that they aren't attached to a class instance. (That's why `self` doesn't make sense in static methods...)

Comment: @TrebledJ Yea thats basically what im asking. A exercise had this as a requirement and I have no clue.

Comment: What exactly are the requirements of this exercise? It's unclear. Please [edit] your question and clarify. Ty.

Comment: You would need to, despite it being static, still pass in the object that you want to modify. Static methods *can* act on instances of a class, it usually just makes more sense to use instance methods, since that's their purpose.

Comment: Since `register_divisible` takes only one parameter... maybe they want `divisible` to be static? Hard to tell.

Comment: @TrebledJ Well even if the attribute was for the class and not the instance, it still can't be changed by a static method right?

Comment: @NikolaO. why not? `System.divisible.append(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, you have to define `divisible` and `obvisible` outside of the constructor and refer variable with class name instead of `self`

```py
class System:
    divisible = []
    obvisible = []

    @staticmethod
    def register_divisible(name):
        System.divisible.append(name)

#Instance        
a=System()
a.register_divisible('one')

#Static
System.register_divisible("two")

print(a.divisible) #prints ['one','two']
print(System.divisible) #prints ['one','two']
```